# Ambiguous Rectangle constructor

Tags: c#

Quick question about the Rectangle constructor in System.Windows.Shapes. I'm trying to create a Rectangle object using the following code.

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(5,5,5,5);
```

However, I get an error saying that the Rectangle constructor doesn't take 4 arguments. After some extensive research, the documentation gives a couple explicit constructors, such as these two.

```
Rectangle(int32,int32, int32, int32);
```

and

```
Rectangle(Point, Size);
```

I have tried using both, and it accepts neither, giving the error that the Rectangle class doesn't accept either 2 or 4 arguments. However, when I don't pass it any arguments, it works fine. The issue is that there is no way to access the location of the Rectangle, so I can only change the width and height after creating the object, not the location.

Disclaimer:

This is indeed part of a homework assignment, but a very, very small piece of a larger whole, and as I have spent a lot of time on this one simple problem(so I assume), therefore, I have no qualms about asking here.

Comment: Just checked the definition. It's namespace System.Windows.Shapes

Comment: Be careful when you read the docs. Key info is hidden in plain sight. See the Namespace and Assembly section at the top. An assembly is one or files (usually one) with one having the assembly metadata. In the metadata, the assembly is given a name and if it declares any types, they are listed. A type is in a hierarchical namespace. The names of the types, namespaces, assembly and files are all independent. Docs on a namespace are usually within the context of a specific set of assemblies. Any number of assemblies can have related or unrelated types with identically named namespaces and types.

Comment: Not quite sure I got all of that, but thanks.

Comment: It relates to the answers given already. The pertinent sets of assemblies are WinForms and WPF.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some back and forth in comments, *this* is what you actually want: A UI element in a `Canvas`, depicting a rectangular shape.

```
var rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();

//  Capital C Canvas: Static methods of System.Windows.Canvas, setting what are 
//  called "attached properties" in WPF. This is very weird if you're new to WPF, sorry. 
Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 5);
Canvas.SetTop(rect, 5);
rect.Height = 5;
rect.Width = 5;

//  canvas, lowercase c, is your instance of System.Windows.Canvas
canvas.Children.Add(rect);
```

With WPF, I prefer to work in XAML rather than C# for creating UI elements:

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="300">
    <Ellipse
        Stroke="DeepSkyBlue"
        Width="30"
        Height="30"
        Canvas.Left="40"
        Canvas.Top="40"
        />
    <Rectangle 
        Stroke="Black"
        StrokeThickness="1"
        Canvas.Left="20" 
        Canvas.Top="20" 
        Width="100" 
        Height="100" 
        />
</Canvas>
```

**Other possible answers, none applicable in this case**

If you're in winforms, use `System.Drawing.Rectangle` instead. That's the one you were reading [the documentation for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) (kudos for actually reading documentation -- few do).

You may possibly have to add to your project a reference to System.Drawing.dll (in References in the project tree in VS).

In WPF, you can use that class, or [`System.Windows.Rect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect(v=vs.110).aspx). That one uses double precision floating point values instead of integers. Pick whichever is appropriate to the task at hand. UI stuff in WPF is all floating point, so `Rect` may be best.

The one in Shapes is something else.

If System.Windows.Shapes is in your using lines at the top, delete that if you can.

But if you need to keep that, this always works in cases of ambiguity:

```
var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(5,5,5,5);
var r2 = new System.Windows.Rect(5,5,5,5);
```

Comment: Ah, that would explain the ambiguity. How would I go about that, however?  I added a using System.Drawing to the code, it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(5,5,5,5);

Comment: What are the using statements at the top of the file?

Comment: @FrederickNoe It's easier to come straight here and act pathetic. For some people.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using static System.Windows.Controls.Slider;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using static System.Math;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Drawing;

Comment: Hmmm, that is quite pathetic. I actually took a lot of time to try to figure it out myself.

Comment: @FrederickNoe are you doing a WPF application ?

Comment: @FrederickNoe Ah yes -- get rid of `using System.Windows.Shapes`

Comment: Yes, I am. @ Ed Plunkett, I would have done that, however I'm also using the Ellipse class for something else, so it's necessary to have...

Comment: @FrederickNoe Ahh. See my updated answer -- you can use the fully resolved class name w/namespace for one or the other.

Comment: @FrederickNoe Also as Jim alludes to, you can use System.Windows.Rect -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, that just shifted the problem. The error it's giving me now is: "The type or namespace Rectangle does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing'(are you missing an assembly reference?).

Comment: Jim's suggestion did fix that constructor issue, but as I want to add it to a canvas (Canvas.Children.Add(rect)), it cannot convert from a rect to an UIElement

Comment: @FrederickNoe OHHHH. OK. `Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 5); Canvas.SetTop(rect, 5);` -- WPF is very weird how it does this stuff with those.

Comment: @FrederickNoe Is your Canvas actually named Canvas, with a capital C? That should change, because it's conflicting with the classname Canvas, if so.

Comment: And the code I am using is: var rect1 = new System.Windows.Rect(5,5,5,5);

Comment: @FrederickNoe OH good. OK, sorry, i ran ahead and forgot to mention: For THIS type of rectangle, a shape displayed in a canvas, you need to be creating System.Windows.Rectangle after all. What a comedy of errors this has been.

Comment: Using this line now. var rect1 = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(5,5,5,5); I am still getting this error. "The type or namespace Rectangle does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing'(are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Indeed, it has been a comedy of errors. I'd like to thank you for helping me with it.

Comment: I would have used XAML, however, this is all inside a function within a class. canvas.SetLeft(rect, 5); canvas.SetRight(rect, 5); are now giving me some errors that I'm not quite sure how to handle. "Member 'Canvas.SetLeft(UI Element, double)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead". WPF can be quite an headache, as I am discovering.

Comment: @FrederickNoe Yeah, you're calling it on lower-case 'c' `canvas` -- that's an instance. You want to call the static method, via upper-case C `Canvas`, the class name: `Canvas.SetLeft`. Your head hasn't even begun to ache. Learning WPF was more painful than teaching myself ANSI C from K&R1. Amazingly powerful, best thing ever, but the learning curve is brutal.

Comment: @FrederickNoe Better rename `canvas`, the instance, to `myCanvas` or something else more visually distinct.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Yeah, the learning curve is tough, especially teaching it to yourself, like I am.

Comment: Good idea, I was just lazy.

Comment: Indeed. There's only one instance of canvas anyway though, I figured it wouldn't matter -_-

Answer (score 3):

In .Net there are two Rectangle classes:

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle(Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32);
System.Drawing.Rectangle(Point, Size);
```

and

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the namespace as below. Add a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` if required.

```
//using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Drawing;
```